# PyPy slow when drawing polygons with PIL/pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pypy

I'm using PIL to draw lots of polygons consisting of big number of points (from couple hundred to couple thousands). With Cpython all polygons were processed 3 times faster than PyPy.
Just to give an example...
One polygon consisting of 352 points:

> PyPy - 0.00620603561401
>   Cpython - 0.000882148742676

```
start = time()
draw.polygon(pixels, outline='rgb(255, 255, 255)', fill='rgb(0, 0, 0)')
print time()-start
```

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and PyPy 1.9 on Ubuntu 12.10
module - Pillow 1.7.8

Comment: Since PIL is written in C PyPy will not give any speed-up to your program. Was this the reason you are trying to run PyPy?

Comment: Also, 0.006 is way too little for the JIT to kick in.

Comment: Bakuriu - Yes, I was hoping PIL will get a boost here. I know JIT needs some time to kick in but, like I mentioned in the post when executing whole script I get 4s in cpython vs 12s in pypy. That is a huge difference.

Comment: @marcin_koss if you are drawing lots of large polygons, then PIL is not what you should be using anyway. Maybe all you are trying to ask  is why operation X is slower in PyPy when compared to cPython, is that the case ?

Comment: @mmgp Well if PIL is a C library and is not fast enough for my needs then what are the chances other C programs will do significantly better? ...and yes it boils down to the question you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @marcin_koss being a C library means nearly nothing. What matters is what are the purposes of the library, and whether they match what you are after. PIL is not intended for the uses you are possibly after, i.e. it doesn't care about implementing efficient routines for the task you are attempting to do because it is not in its scope to provide such thing.